# Why is the button disappearing?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import random
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("700x500")         
root.title("rolling dice")

def roll():
    l1=Label(root,font=("times",200)) 
    faces=["\u2680","\u2681","\u2682","\u2683","\u2684","\u2685"]    
    l1.configure(text=f"{random.choice(faces)}{random.choice(faces)}")
    l1.pack()

b1 = Button(root,text="Lets roll", command=roll)
b1.place(x=340,y=0)             
root.mainloop()
```

If I mention the label l1 before def then it is doing what is expected, but I am not able to understand what is happening when I mention it inside def.

Comment: add `b1.lift()` after `l1.pack()` under `roll()` function.

Comment: It is because the label overlaps the button so it hides the button.  BTW, it is better to create the label outside the function and update the text of the label if needed.

Comment: Thanks man, you saved me a lot of time

Comment: just replace `b1.place(x=340,y=0)` with `b1.pack(side=BOTTOM)`. Dont mix `place()` with `pack()` or `grid()` and it is always better to use `pack()` or `grid()` over `place()`. Place is for static UI whereas the others are better for automatic scaling.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the button disappearing?

The reasoning why is because you set the font size to 200. When you press the button the font size overlapped the `Button`. The `Button` has not disappeared. It is still behind font size.

The easier way to do it is to set the coordinate of a y-axis to 20.

- Add `pady=20` in `l1.pack(pady=20)`.
- Move `Label` and `pack` out side of the function.

Don't use wildcard import *. Use `import tkinter as tk`. Then do prefix `tk.`

Snippet: I modified it to make readability.

```
import random
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("700x500")         
root.title("rolling dice")

def roll():    
    faces=["\u2680","\u2681","\u2682","\u2683","\u2684","\u2685"]    
    l1.configure(text=f"{random.choice(faces)}{random.choice(faces)}")
     
b1 = tk.Button(root, text="Lets roll", command=roll)
b1.place(x=340, y=0)

l1 = tk.Label(root,font=("times",200))
l1.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]